# Running a java application from a web application

Tags: java

Is it possible to call from a web application running on a server, another application on the machine client, in a way that the application on the machine client will receive some informations that it will use to run a calcul, that once is done, it will return the result to the server?

The application runing on the server is a JAVA/JEE app based on Spring, and on the client is a java application

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Provided that your Spring application is implementing a REST service and provides endpoints for manipulating data, you can easily interact with that application using a client on any device, whether it's an application on a machine or a mobile.

Comment: It sounds like you've designed a really strange system. Why do you need to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use, for example RMI or a simple REST-Client to interact with the web application.

Comment: Just because you mention the RMI you have my vote. But you could add some doc or example.